# Desktop app access to Active Directory via MS Graph using vb.net

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am unfortunately trying unsuccessfully to log my desktop app into active directory via ms graph. I want to get access to the groups assigned to the current user.

the app is registered in AD and I have the tenantId, clientId, clientSecret and the RedirectURI.

unfortunately no code example from the web has brought any result. According to my current understanding, in the first step I need to retrieve a token on the Microsoft identity platform to then log the app into AD and retrieve the appropriate info.

My first question would be is that undertsandng correct? and if so how should the code look like.

Any help would be great. Thanks